# How to block specific notifications from an app?

Tags: notifications, filter

A certain app I use gives me crucial notifications that I need, but also notifies me almost daily that over 80% of my RAM is used. I would like to allow this app to send me all notifications except those that contain the string "80% of your RAM" in the text of the notification.

Obviously, there is no way to filter a certain app's notifications in stock Android (other than blocking all of a certain app's notifications, but that's not what I want!), but is there a way that I can block notifications if they contain a certain string of text?

Nexus 6P running Android Marshmallow 6.0.1, if you're curious the app in question is [CM Security](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.security).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you use MacroDroid or a similar app, such as Automate.

[MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) defines a set of trigger(s), action(s) and constraint(s) as a macro. You **must enable** Notification access permission and Usage Access permission in it.

You would be needing the following macro.

- *Trigger*:  Notification → Notification Received:

  - *From*: choose your app
  - *Text Content*: here's where you can play. Choose *Contains* or *Matches* to filter your text specific notification.
- *Action*:

  - Clear Notifications → Select Application(s) → select your app → provide the filtering details again
- *Constraints*: none

Save the macro and you're good to go.

**Note**: MacroDroid can remove sticky/persistent notifications only in Android Oreo and above.

Comment: **Update in 2022:** this solution [reportedly](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/248885/possible-moisture-detected-in-the-charging-port-error-on-samsung-galaxy-s10?noredirect=1#comment334908_248885) worked on Galaxy S10+ (presumably running Android 12) too.