# How to Remove persistent "Samsung Account" notification? It keeps showing up regardless of settings

Tags: samsung, notifications

I have been struggling to find out how to turn off (or otherwise hide) the notification that says:

> Samsung account 
> Tap here to use your Samsung Account

[image]

I've read elsewhere online about ways to stop this, but they don't seem to be working.  I tapped the notification, held down and went to "Details" on the Notification.

According to that screen, I shouldn't be getting these notifications but still am.

[image]
How can I turn this off (*without* signing in to Samsung or creating an account)?

(Galaxy S8 Active, Android 8.0.0, Samsung Experience Version 9.0)

Edit: 9 November 2018 - Now the notification is showing and making a "text message" noise. I still can't figure out how to stop this!

Edit: 17 Dec. 2018 - Still getting the notification *multiple times per hour* sometimes, and it makes the text message noise. I've done everything I can find online and there's no solution still...

Edit: Nov 2020 - whelp my s8 galaxy bit the dust and I got an S10. It doesn't appear to have this issue, but unfortunately am no closer in learning how to stop the notification

Comment: Why don't you just create an account and sign in?

Comment: @ShaunRoselt Users may not want to create Samsung accounts due to privacy considerations, not wanting to give personal data to even more companies. If a Samsung account is not required for using the device, it should be possible to disable this notification without signing into a Samsung account.

Comment: @inquiryqueue - Exactly.  And, IIRC the notification has never appeared when I had my S6 Active, I think 3 years ago, until the most recent Android update on my S8 Active.  So it's certainly not required at all.

Comment: For me this also started happening with the most recent update, after about a year with the same phone.

Comment: For folks who come to this question seeking solution see if my answer helps you out: [How to block specific notifications from an app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/163569/96277)

Answer (score 1):

Constantly had the notification appearing and making noises, tried everything but nothing worked until I tried this;

1. Settings
2. Select "Notifications"
3. Tap "Advanced" (top right corner)
4. Tap the 3 dots in the top right-hand corner and select "Show system apps"
5. Scroll down to "Samsung Account"
6. Turn off

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately I have done that, it's off and notifications are blocked, but I'm still getting the notifications.

Comment: It's impossible. The notifications are enabled, and switch to turn it off is disabled.

Comment: The only thing I could do was switch Alerts to "silent"