# How to dismiss non-removable notifications?

Tags: applications, huawei

So I've got a new Android phone like a week ago. But still couldn't get used to it. Still, couldn't figure out some part that how is it workes. Now, this is about notifications I get by installed apps. On the drop-down menu, I get it usually but some of these notifications are not removing even if I try to remove it. Most of them are saying that some kind of app running. And it won't dismissive.

Does anyone have any idea how to remove these non-removable notifications?

Comment: I don't know about making them removable but MacroDroid app can swipe them away automatically. https://android.stackexchange.com/a/163569/96277

Comment: What version of Android are you running? The point of these notifications is that they remain there to warn you that the app is doing something, but if you really don't care about them you could, depending on your version, long-press them and mute them in the settings.