# Disable "DeX on PC" notification each time S10 connected to PC

Tags: notifications, samsung-dex

Since a recent update (I can't say exactly which or when) each time I connect my Samsung S10 to my PC, I get a `Samsung DeX` notification...

[image]

I don't want DeX, but I do want to get rid of the notification every time I connect my phone.

Is it possible disable/remove the notification?  The `app notifications` is not giving me the slide-switch option to disable it...

[image]

Comment: See if my answer helps. https://android.stackexchange.com/q/163338/96277

Comment: Thanks @Firelord - I was hoping there might be a quick and easy solution, but I'll have a look at MacroDroid over the weekend when I have a bit of time

Answer (score 9):

If you would rather remove Dex from your phone instead of disabling it, and you have [ADB and USB debugging setup](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/), you can remove it with this command:

```
adb shell "pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.sec.android.app.dexonpc"
```

Answer (score 2):

Open Settings, go to Apps. Press the three dot symbol, and tap "show system apps". Then go to Dex for PC, tap storage, clear cache. Go back one screen, tap Force stop and Disable. You might have to repeat this after reboot or software upgrade, haven't tested that.