# Annoying "No data service" alert

Tags: notifications, mobile-data, alerts

[image: Message]

I'm receiving this stupid message every 5 minutes.

How to disable it **without** disabling other important messages of similar category ?

Comment: See if my answer works for you. https://android.stackexchange.com/a/163569/96277

Comment: Read these posts: https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/how-do-i-turn-off-the-no-service-notification.79007/#post-7386695 || https://forums.att.com/conversations/android/turn-off-no-data-service-notifications/5df00728bad5f2f6069ded57

Comment: I used NotifyClean before on android 6, but it doesn't seem to be working on Oreo. Says "mudule not active or didn't reboot". Needless to say, both are false.

Comment: Read the posts. Their problems are quite similar, but their solution is like exploding a kitchen to kill a single cockroach. They disable phone notifications altogether, including the important ones.

Comment: Thinking back at the NotifyClean solution, it's still not the ideal, since, unless I'm wrong, the visual message will be suppressed, but the audio notification will still be there to piss me

Answer (score 1):

I've also had the problem of a notification alert every 5 seconds. I think I solved the problem by doing the following.

1. Make a recording in a quiet place and make sure there is no sound recorded. (only 1 sec needed.
2. Save the recording as "No Sound" or what you want.
3. Locate the recording in "File", "Audio"
4. On the 3 dots select to set it as "Notification"
5. On the main menu settings select this as your "Notification sound"
6. Go to your other application ("What's app", "SMS", "eMail", etc.) and change the notification sound from "Default sound" to your required tune.

You will still receive the message but it won't make a sound.

Hope this makes sense and will help solve the annoying notification.