# How to hide "Do not disturb" notification card

Tags: notifications

Is there a way to hide this notification card?

[image]

I have Huawei P30 with an up-to-date Android 10 (EMUI 10.1.0 - Build version 10.1.0.133) and I believe this card started showing up after a recent update (which happened in the past 2-4 weeks).

I keep my phone on DND most of the time, but I'm pretty sure this card wasn't there before when DND would be on. It's just noise (since I have the DND button in the drawer anyway and it's blue which signifies that DND is on), it's occupying space, and I don't want it to be displayed (but I want my DND to stay on during certain hours). Is there a way to make this specific notification not show up - ever?

Pressing the "Disable" button actually disables DND.

Thanks.

Comment: See if this helps:https://android.stackexchange.com/a/163569/96277