# turn off phone services notification

Tags: notifications, bloatware

A happy owner of a palm phone, though every time the phone is turned off then on or restarted, it shows a notification that a non-verizon sim is being used. I understand these were exclusively verison prior and there is not an unbranded firmware readily available for these, but would still like to ask about a way to remove this particular category from the phone services app.

When long pressing on the notification is shows as 'name_verizon_wireless_notification_channel' but the option to disable this category in the phone services notification settings is greyed out. I have removed much of the verizon bloatware by uninstalling the packages with abd shell. Is there a way to enable this toggle or otherwise remove it from phone services?

[image: notification]

[image: notification details]

[image: notification settings]

Comment: If you are running Android 8 or above you can try MacroDroid to clear that particular notification automatically. See my answer https://android.stackexchange.com/a/163569/96277