# 'Wifi calling' notification impossible to remove

Tags: notifications, android-11

At the top of my notifications for the last 2 years or so, there's been a notification that says:

```
Wi-fi Calling
Tap here to confirm or update emergency location information for Wi-Fi Calling.
This will allow you to make and receive voice calls when a mobile network isn't available.
```

I don't want to use wifi calling, I can't get rid of this notification. There's no way to silence, hide, mute, or do anything to the notification. Wifi calling is disabled in settings. Clicking the notification shows a loading symbol and 'Loading, this may take a few moments' for about a minute and a half, then gives an error that says 'Unable to activate wi-fi calling at this time. Please try again later.'. It does this with or without wifi being connected or enabled, and with or without a sim card.

I have tried everything I could possibly find on google, to no hope. I don't want to reset the phone or root it just to get rid of a notification.

The phone is a Galaxy S10+ with Android 11 on Verizon

Comment: See if my answer helps : https://android.stackexchange.com/a/163569/96277