# How do I block the Tethering and Hotspot Active notification from showing?

Tags: tethering

The device is Samsung Galaxy M31. I have searched for a method but couldn't find out. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Make your search query generic. Such as, how to hide or remove a system app persistent/sticky  notification in Android. See my answer. https://android.stackexchange.com/q/163338/96277

Comment: @Firelord thanks!