# Possible "moisture detected in the charging port" error on Samsung Galaxy S10+

Tags: charging, samsung-galaxy-s-10

A few weeks ago an error message popped up on my phone:

> Warning: Do not use charging/USB port We've detected moisture or
> foreign material in your charging/USB port.  Check your charging/USB
> port for any foreign material such as dust and debris. To prevent
> damage to your phone, don't plug anything until charging port is
> clean, the moisture is gone, and the notification is cleared.

The issue is that the phone was laying on my desk when the notification first occurred. There was no water near the phone and it never got wet. I used a can of air to clear out any possible dust but there was none that I could see. I have tried to restart my phone but the notification has not cleared even after a reboot. I do not want to poke around in the charging port with a pair of needle nose tweezers.

The only way the phone will charge is wirelessly which is inconvenient, especially in the car. I believe that this is some type of bug in the script considering it popped up out of nowhere. I do not want to factory reset, is there a process that could clear this manually through the operating system?

Comment: Hello. Do you want to just hide the notification or you wanna figure out what actually led the system (whatever app/service that is) to conclude that the charging port has moisture or debris in contact? For the former case, do you not get an option to hide the notification if you long-press on it? If you get one you can follow it into Settings app and hide that particular notification. If you don't get the relevant option than you can use MacroDroid to remove the notification automatically.

Comment: ...See example at: [How to block specific notifications from an app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/163338/96277).

Comment: It does not allow me to hide the notification as it originates from the Android System. It only allows me to silence it for at most an hour. I am interested in the MacroDroid solution though. Could you possibly create that as an answer?

Comment: I was hoping you could tell me what worked or did not work there for you so that I could update my answer. I have an old Android version (v10) and a non-Samsung device, and I cannot update my MacroDroid (because it would check for license verification with Google Play Services which I have deliberately botched) :) Try the linked post (has my own answer there). If that doesn't work I'll try something else.

Comment: It worked. I was able to clear the notification. Update away :)