# Which notification settings controls Family Link notifications?

Tags: notifications, google-family-link

I have migrated my daughter's phone from Microsoft Launcher to Google Family Link. Everything works as expected (or even better) and the only problem (or actually one of [two problems](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/249710/20449)) we're facing is the irritating notification that Family Link displays:

[image]

How can I get rid of it?

I have tried to open the corresponding app (Google) notification settings. I found many entries there, but nothing that seems to be related to Family Link.

On one of two phones, I managed to resolve this by completely disabling the Google application from displaying any kind of notifications. But that's a workaround I'd like to avoid the most, if possible.

Comment: I don't use Google Family Link so I cannot check if my answer would. It is worth a try though. See [How to block specific notifications from an app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/163569/96277). The app you need to target is Google Play Services.

Comment: The notification shows "Google Play services" as the source of the notification. You might be able to access the notification setting directly by long-pressing the notification. However, that doesn't mean that there's a notification setting for Family Link *specifically* if Google doesn't provide a notification channel for this.

Comment: It seems that disabling "Google Play services" notification, as you both suggest, will resolve this issue. However, it will also block any forthcoming notifications from Google Play, for example some game-related notifications. It's a trade-off that I am willing to accept. However, I am really, really surprised that given the fact that dozens, if not hundreds of millions of parents are using Family Link, they haven't still come with the separate setting. I don't mind my girls having full games-related notifications and I don't see anything in common between Google Play games and Family Link.

Comment: This seems very weird. I'll do some tests and report here. Thank you.