# Unable to uninstall Microsoft Launcher or Microsoft Family Safety. Apps are installed back automatically

Tags: android-11, miui-13

I have migrated my daughters phone from Microsoft Launcher to Google Family Link. Everything works as expected (or even better) but the problem we're facing is that we cannot uninstall Microsoft stuff from the phone -- namely Microsoft Launcher and Microsoft Family Safety.

Steps:

1. We locate the application's icon in the app drawer (Android 11, Xiaomi Redmi 11S, MIUI 13) and trying to uninstall it the regular way:

[image]

2. We're hit with the confirmation message:

[image]

3. After so-called uninstallation process corresponding icon disappears:

[image]

4. Only to reappear about 2-3 seconds later:

[image]

Microsoft stuff (FamilySafety and Lanuncher) are the only apps that we cannot uninstall, we can uninstall any other without any problems.

As you can see, a bare Google / MIUI app drawer and launcher is in use. Microsoft Launcher has been (successfully?) removed as a home screen launcher.

What we're doing wrong or how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Just checking if you tried to disable the Microsoft apps in Google Family Link.

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing that I did. A workaround that just works. But by no means answer why suddenly I cannot uninstall an app from my phone. An app that I have manually and myself installed. To be honest, this is the first time in the past 10 years that I have come with such a weird situation. We all have heard about hundreds of apps that you cannot remove from your phone, but it was always apps that have come to you with the phone. I have never heard about the situation where I can install something myself only to not being able to uninstall this thing later. Really, really weird.

Comment: Also checking if you did: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/uninstalling-the-microsoft-family-safety-app-97685a5c-4847-421a-a234-330a7642526b as it sounds like the Microsoft device manager or some other device manager (Google / Xiaomi ?) is still active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the nature of usage, both apps (*Microsoft Launcher* and *Microsoft Family Safety*) are setup with the *Device Admin* permission during installation. This permission must be revoked before one can uninstall it (or any other app with such permission). And some additional steps may be needed.

For *Microsoft Family Safety* (instructions from source adjusted to Redmi 11S):

1. Sign out from your child’s account in Family Safety app (tap on the app’s menu button → Settings → Sign out) on your child phone
2. Depending on child’s age, family organizer approval may be needed
3. Exit app and go to Settings → Privacy protection → Special permissions → Device admin apps → *Family Safety* → Deactivate this device admin app

For *Microsoft Launcher* (on Redmi 11S):

1. Go to Settings → Privacy protection → Special permissions → Device admin apps → *Family Safety* → Deactivate this device admin app
2. Go to Settings → Home screen → Default launcher → deactivate *Microsoft Launcher* (change it to some other)

Now you can uninstall these apps the regular way and they won't be reinstalled automatically.

Source: [Uninstalling the Microsoft Family Safety app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/uninstalling-the-microsoft-family-safety-app-97685a5c-4847-421a-a234-330a7642526b).