# How can I disable permission monitoring on Android 13?

Tags: security, notifications, permissions, android-13

I recently upgraded from a Samsung Galaxy S9+ to the S23 Ultra and noticed that it almost daily pushes notifications like this:

> Settings:
> Android System Intelligence got your location in the
> background.  This app can always access your location. Tap to change.

When I long-press to change the notification settings, it looks like the notification is coming from "Permission controller" - and the "allow notifications" option is disabled (and on), with no options to disable notifications for subcategories either.

I granted these permissions and really dont want to see this daily, it is a bit obnoxious in my opinion.

I read [this article from 2018](https://nerdschalk.com/how-to-disable-the-app-permission-monitors-persistent-notification-on-galaxy-s8-note-8-and-s9/#:%7E:text=1%20From%20the%20home%20screen%20of%20your%20Galaxy,notification%20should%20go%20away%20from%20the%20notification%20window.) saying this could be disabled, however, on this phone I do not have this option. There is no "Lock screen and security" option - these were split into two different menu screens now. The Lock Screen menu screen has no such options. The Security and Privacy menu has a "Permission manager" option under the "Privacy" option, but there are no options anywhere to disable it.

**I would like to disable this without rooting the phone.** Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi. If immediate automatic dismissal of that notification is acceptable as a solution,  see if my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/163569/96277) works for you. You would have to use "Permission controller" as the target app in that answer.

Comment: Just following up, thanks for suggesting this - it worked pretty well and also is a pretty good app, thanks again!

Comment: No problem @MarkL. :)

Answer (score -1):

I have Android 13 on Note 20.  I don't get those notifications.

It seems to me that you can either disable the **Permission Manager** or notifications from it, or you could change the permissions of **Android System Intelligence**

For that

- Go to Settings
- Select Apps
- Press on 3 vertical dots on top right
- Select Permission Manager
- Select Location
- Select Android System Intelligence
- Remove the Location Permission from it.

Comment: The Permission Manager does not have the option to be disabled or to disable notifications, which I explained in my question. And I am not looking to change any of my permissions for apps, my question is about suppressing the notification of what permissions I am using, since I already know what permissions I have granted and don't need reminders.