# Disable repeated "High mobile data usage" notification?

Tags: mobile-data, android-12, google-pixel

It seems that once the data warning point I have set is passed, Android keeps showing the notification below, even though

- I have dismissed this same notification multiple times.
- Cellular data has never been enabled since the last same notification, so there is no new data usage since the last notification.

It almost seems like a bug, but if it is not a bug, how can I disable this notification at least for this month, other than removing data warning point in Settings?

[image]

Comment: See if my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/163569/96277) works out. In the answer set "Constraints" to "Day of the Month" or "Month of the Year" or use both.