# Prevent notifications on SMS messages from a contact during off hours on Google Messages

Tags: notifications, sms, automation, google-pixel, google-messages

I'm using Pixel 7a and Google Messages. I wonder if there is a setting or an app to stop notifications on texts message coming from people I cannot block during off-hours in a systematic way: e.g. Every Monday morning.

---

Playing with [MacroDroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacroDroid) as suggested, I wouldn't mind getting feedback on the multiple options to set this up. For instance, an initial walk-through of the app has led me to place the phone on "Do Not Disturb" for any incoming messages, which is not what I was after.

Here is a macro trying to approximate the intended outcome, i.e. any text (SMS) from Jack received on Tuesday morning will stop the notification sound that I have as a default.

[image]

Is this correct? After it triggers, will the notification sound be disabled for all incoming messages regardless of the sender's name (or number) until I reset it in my phone settings?

Comment: Using an automation is one option. See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/163569/131553) //In constraints section of the macro, you add the conditions under which you want the macro to run (day of the week And (logical operator), time)

Comment: @beeshyams I can't figure out how to stop the audio notification sound just for that specific person on MacroDroid.

Comment: I suggest you edit the question to include what the notification text includes (person's name) and from which app do you get the notification(sl) / It's doable but right now I am not inclined to spend efforts(hint: see the options under notification received trigger for apps and the notification text)

Comment: @beeshyams OK. I did edit the question to make it more concrete. Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your phone model, you may be able to accomplish this via Do Not Disturb. Here's how I did it on my Pixel 6 Pro running Android 13:

- Open Settings > Search 'Do Not Disturb'
- Click "Schedules"
- Click "Add more" and choose "Time"
- Customize the Days, Start and End times
- Click "Do Not Disturb behavior" > "Create custom settings for this schedule" (see screengrab below)
- Use the "Calls" and "Messages" settings to determine who is allowed through the Do Not Disturb settings

There are a lot of ways to accomplish what you want from here. The easiest way for messages (if you're using Google Messages) is to choose "Priority conversations" in Messages, then pick which texts threads are allowed through. Another way for calls and texts is to add people to your "Starred contacts" and only allow those during your chosen time.

Note, instead of "Schedules" in the second step, you can also choose "Event" to use your Google Calendar to decide when to apply these settings, which may be better depending on your use case.

[image: Sorry for the terrible quality, the 2mb limit is rough for .gif files]

Comment: I must have done something wrong. It blocked my alarm clock, and media sounds, etc.

Comment: Be sure to look inside the "Create custom settings for this schedule" (press the gear) under "Do Not Disturb behavior" when creating the schedule. This is where you'll find toggles for turning on Alarms, Media sounds, Touch sounds, etc. I'll try to add a quick screen grab.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Android version, users have more control in 13 & up over Notification Permissions. Can be controlled per App or Notifications for all apps link below M. Android device Settings will give an option of which all apps to allow Notifications at all, popup, or silent, etc.

Google Help topic: [Change app permissions on your Android phone](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9431959).

You can also use the "Manage notifications" screen to block notifications from specific apps or to change the priority of notifications.

Maybe will help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there might be another option and it was partially answered above.

As a user, I believe your best bet is to first organize your Contacts into Groups and add Labels for ex; "Trainees" or "Company partner" etc. Then you can easily scroll through and tag each quickly as a FAVORITE (star it).

When you're off yet can't block 1 contact or several, you can still set DND yet make the allowance of Allow Notifications and/or calls from certain people or your FAVORITES. This might take about 30 to organize contacts but I believe it will work. I hope so. Although I am still researching a bit. it should not change or mute alarms.

Google Help topic: [View, group & share contacts](https://support.google.com/contacts/answer/30970?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid).

Answer (score 0):

To mute notifications from an individual contact in the Messages app:

1. Open Google Messages with said contact in mind.

   - You can either open a temp new chat message to the contact without adding input, or
   - Open an already existing (*ongoing or archived doesn't matter) as long as desired contact name is showing.
2. In either scenario, go to the upper right-hand corner (on Android) or DETAILS on a different device:
3. Tap DETAILS
4. Tap NOTIFICATIONS
5. Select: SILENT

[image: Screenshot of messages Details Menu]
[image: Details Menu #2 Notification]

This will mute all notifications from this contact while using Google Messages app. Temporarily at least until you mark at the bottom of the same screen where it says "Set this as not a conversation." That will move it back from Conversation to Chat; normal chat contact status. That Conversation might be found in the All or possibly even Archived category, but it hasn't been deleted unless you did.

I don't use the individual notifications conversation windows, but you can also set a ***NOTIFICATION SOUND*** per Contact if you wanted.  The Settings is in that same Detail screen and Menu.

Hope this does it.